How to automatically generate P/Invoke interface of Jolt Physics(C++ lib) for Unity?
I want to use double precision(position and velocity) physics engine in Unity for aerospace simulation. Unity6 supports .Net Standard 2.1 and C#9, with csc.rsp it can use part of C#10 syntax like file scoped namespace and unmanaged function pointer like
delegate* unmanaged[Cdecl] <int, int>. Jolt Physics engine is a good choice for my requirement, but it's written in C++, with a huge number of APIs, so it's hard for me to write and maintain updates for manually written [DllImport] interface and data structs. JoltPhysicsSharp library supports .NET8, but it's not suit for Unity due to used a lot of new .NET features. I tried to use ClangSharp P/Invoke Generator to generate api p/invoke interface, with generate.rsp like following:
--namespace
JoltUnity.Interop

--file
Jolt.h

--methodClassName
JoltUnity

--libraryPath
Jolt.dll

-std
c++17

--additional
-m64

--define-macro
JPH_DOUBLE_PRECISION

--output
../Jolt.Net

--config
multi-file
generate-file-scoped-namespaces
generate-setslastsystemerror-attribute

I put it in folder JoltPhysics/Jolt/ , install it as dotnet tool install --global ClangSharpPInvokeGenerator, run ClangSharpPInvokeGenerator "@generate.rsp" in VS2022 developer powershell, and got message:
fatal error: 'Jolt/Core/Core.h' file not found. And I tried put it in JoltPhysics/ root folder with changing --file to jolt/Jolt.h; and put other header files like Jolt/Core/Core.h into --file, and other tries so on. I've read the generator's manual, and some blogs on google, asked ChatGPT, many many tries, but nothing worked. Maybe I missed some important details, but what is it?
related links:
ClangSharpPInvokeGenerator example on github
JoltPhysics on github

I have always done this type of mapping by the tedious process of manually entering the C# code to access the library. You only have to do it once. But having said that, I would (in Dec 2024) ask CoPilot (Or ChatGPT) to do the translation for me. Way more efficient and faster and less error prone. (Note: I am not "using chat GPT" to generate any of this answer.)   (Creds... I wrote the original complete mapping from C# to Steam)
